# Полу стационарные отделения, но полустационар

Tags: недопустимая-метка

По Лопатину: Недопустимо слитное или дефисное написание с приставкой или первой частью сложного слова, если вторая часть содержит пробел, т. е. представляет собой сочетание слов: полу дачные посёлки, полу дом отдыха (но полудача), полу литературный фельетон,  полу детский сад.

такой же принцип с *экс*: экс главный редактор, но экс-редактор

Значит, полу стационарное отделение?

но всюду только такое написание:

СТАЦИОНАРНОЕ И ПОЛУСТАЦИОНАРНОЕ ЛЕЧЕНИЕ

полустационарной психиатрической помощи.

в диссертации: Формирование социально-культурной активности пожилых людей в полустационарных учреждениях социальной защиты

из приказа: Укрепление материально-технической базы стационарных и полустационарных учреждений

из типовых правил:
социального обслуживания в психоневрологических медико-социальных учреждениях (организациях) полустационарного типа;

и так далее.

Comment: Как отличить, относится полу только к первому слову или к сочетанию слов?

Comment: Не вижу другого способа, кроме как по смыслу. Кстати, "полудачные поселки" я бы писал слитно. А "полу литературный фельетон" я вообще не понимаю, что такое. Да и "полу детский сад" тоже. Но тут "полудетский" явно не напишешь.

Answer (score 4):

Во всех лопатинских примерах "полу" относится ко всему словосочетанию (особенно ясно это видно в "полу дом отдыха"). В вашем же случае "полу" относится только к "стационарному".